# Should Doctrine DataFixtures be isolated from the logic in a custom bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm wondering about best practices when it comes to DataFixtures with Symfony2. For example, I have `Role` and `User`.

**RoleFixtures:**

```
class RoleFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $userRole = new Role();
        $userRole->setName("user");
        $userRole->setRole("ROLE_USER");
        $manager->persist($userRole);
        $manager->flush();

        $adminRole = new Role();
        $adminRole->setName("admin");
        $adminRole->setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
        $manager->persist($adminRole);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

**UserFixtures:**

```
class UserFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $roleManager = $this->container->get('elite_fifa.role_manager');
        $userRole = $roleManager->getRoleByName("user");
        $adminRole = $roleManager->getRoleByName("admin");

        $userManager = $this->container->get('elite_fifa.user_manager');

        $user1 = $userManager->createUser();
        $user1->setUsername("user1");
        $user1->setEmail("my1@email.com");
        $user1->addRole($userRole);
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user1);
        $encodedPass = $encoder->encodePassword('pass1', $user1->getSalt());
        $user1->setPassword($encodedPass);
        $manager->persist($user1);
        $manager->flush();

        $user2 = $userManager->createUser();
        $user2->setUsername("user2");
        $user2->setEmail("my2@email.com");
        $user2->addRole($adminRole);
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user2);
        $encodedPass = $encoder->encodePassword('pass2', $user1->getSalt());
        $user2->setPassword($encodedPass);
        $manager->persist($user2);
        $manager->flush();

    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Take a look at the load method in UserFixtures, can I use `$roleManager->getRoleByName("user")` instead of using DataFixtures built in `references`?

I was thinking by doing it my way I am reusing code and adding another path to test. But is it bad practice to couple Fixtures with the bundles logic? Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more in detail why you aren't using the builtin `references` feature? What do you mean by adding another path to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it depends on one question: **What do you use these fixtures for?**

- For your application (create users and roles which are necessary to bootstrap the app). In this case, I wouldn't mind using the bundle logic, as it can have business logic inside that you want to re-use.
- For your tests (I think that's what you're doing). In this case, you don't want to use the bundle logic. It's true that it "adds another path to test", but you should separate all your tests, or when you change your RoleManager logic, you will have more failing tests than necessary. Tests should be as independent as possible, each one testing one thing at a time.